# Допустимо ли тире?

Tags: тире

> Это не значит, что, по крайней мере, в рамках тех мощностей и
>   аппарата, которые даны нам эволюцией, мы совершенно беспомощны — если
>   бы так было, мы бы не выжили.

Здесь интонационное тире, или отделена вставная конструкция, или что-то другое? Если вставная, разве допустимо выделять её тире в конце предложения, а не скобками?

> И пока никто не ответил, ещё одно: Это не было бы так страшно, если бы
>   она (экономика) не имела столь внушительного влияния на наши жизни, но
>   в том и дело, что она ими располагает — и активно навязывается нам, —
>   что перестаёт быть смешным и превращается в нечто угрожающее и опасное
>   — а то и гротескное вперемешку с карикатурным.

Теперь тире перед "а". Это вставная конструкция со знач. уточнения? И если она в конце предложения, можно ли тире оставить или лучше скобки? Или это не вставная, а автор интонационно подчеркивает последнюю часть, и запятая перед союзом "а" опускается?

Comment: ***По крайней мере*** здесь не вводное сочетание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому предложению. Это интонационное тире, которое более выразительно при наличии множества запятых.
По второму. Это авторское тире, которое также интонационно подчеркивает эту присоединительную конструкцию. По правилам перед присоединительным союзом "а то и" ставится запятая.

Comment: Большое спасибо!